# How to combine is_category() and query_posts() in an if..else statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few snippets of code where I want to check if the category is correct and if post actually exist, at the moment I have an if_category() function that then queries my required category but I think these are clashing so none of my posts for the category are being displayed, can anyone advise how I can fix this code?

PHP

```
<?php if(is_category('Rainwater Harvesting Product')) { ?>
            <!-- Related Projects -->
            <?php query_posts('category_name=rainwater-harvesting-project&showposts=5'); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) { ?>
                <div class="aside-mod related-projects">
                    <div class="curved-ctn">
                    <h2 class="module-header">Related Projects</h2>

                        <ul class="project-list clearfix">
                                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                    <li class="project">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="project">
                                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                              the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                                            } ?>

                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <!-- <i class="icon-project"></i> -->

                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey, it uses a custom post template which is used along with the plugin Custom Post Template http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because in your
`<?php query_posts('category_name=Greywater Recycling Project&showposts=5'); ?>` 
you are giving to category_name, the Name instead of the category slug, the query_posts parameter, category_name takes only the slug. eg: it must be

`<?php query_posts('category_name=greywater-recycling-project&showposts=5'); ?>`

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Hi, I updated my code but still the query is being ignored. It appears that problem is with is_category() removing this conditional displays the posts but I need the is_category() conditional?

Comment: hey i changed from is_category() to in_category() and it works!